# How to debug PHP functions with FirePHP when the function definition and invocation are not in the same file?

Tags: php, firephp

I have installed FirePHP, and can get output on console with the following example:

```
<?php
require_once('FirePHPCore/fb.php');  
ob_start(); 

function hello() {
  fb('Hello World!', FirePHP::TRACE);
}
function greet() {
  hello();
}
greet();

?>
```

But if I move the `greet();` to another php file, I can get nothing on console. I have tried to include the `require_once` & `ob_start` in both files, but it didn't take effect. 
How to debug PHP functions with FirePHP when the function definition and invocation are not in the same file?

Comment: Thx, Ryan. I find there is output on console with this simple case, with two php files. But I still fail to get output with my big/old project. Have tried to remove ?>, also checked the file dir.  In my project, one php file has more than one `<?php...?>`, and there is html code between two `<?php...?>`. Could you please give me some more suggestions? @Ryan Vincent

Comment: I tried `var_dump('function exists? : func*', function_exists('func*'), __FILE__.__LINE__);`, the functions I need both shows `bool(true)`. Also I tried one function not included, the result shows `bool(false)`.

Comment: So I think the include relationship is right, but still fail to output with my project... The rough file structure is as follows:  
a.php
************************************
<?php
require_once('FirePHPCore/fb.php');
require_once('b.php');
ob_start();
...

greet();
...
?>

<?php
...
function greet() {
    hello();
}
...
************************************

b.php
************************************
<?php
...
function hello() {
    fb('Hello World!', FirePHP::TRACE);
}
...
?>
************************************

Comment: The only distinction is there is html code between the two `<?php ... ?>` in a.php.